# App Crashes after adding new Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im new at development and i started following this tutorial to create a message app:
http://sinch.github.io/android-messaging-tutorial/

After adding the second Activity(ListUsersActivity) and its layout file, everytime when i run the app it crashes, dont know why exactly.

Here's the ListUsersActivity:

```
package com.sinch.messagingtutorialskeleton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.messagingtutorialskeleton.R;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ListUsersActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
    setContentView(com.example.messagingtutorialskeleton.R.layout.activity_list_users);
        logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
        logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ParseUser.logOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        setConversationList();
    }

    private void setConversationList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List <ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userList.get(i).getUsername().toString());
                    }

                    usersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                    namesArrayAdapter =
                            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                                    R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You clicked on user: " + i,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Look up user id and open conversation
            }
        });
    }

    private Button logoutButton;
    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ListView usersListView;
}
```

Now the MainActivity(LoginActivity):

```
package com.sinch.messagingtutorialskeleton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.messagingtutorialskeleton.R;
import com.parse.LogInCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        //start new activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListUsersActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    setContentView(com.example.messagingtutorialskeleton.R.layout.activity_login);
    Parse.initialize(this, "uUv5HM8nqz9gVQBDWaw1bDLxbD3SFQPQtvDESJG1", "BHVp4MQbiOODY3yGOrM7pgaZ0xTbCPI1v6dfRU6C");
    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    signUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
    usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUsername);
    passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);


    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            username = usernameField.getText().toString();
            password = passwordField.getText().toString();

            ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        //start new activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListUsersActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Wrong username/password combo",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });

    signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sign Up",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            username = usernameField.getText().toString();
            password = passwordField.getText().toString();

            ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setPassword(password);

            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        //start new activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListUsersActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "There was an error signing up."
                                , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private Button signUpButton;
private Button loginButton;
private EditText usernameField;
private EditText passwordField;
private String username;
private String password;

}
```

The AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.messagingtutorialskeleton" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"> >
    <activity
        android:name="com.sinch.messagingtutorialskeleton.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.sinch.messagingtutorialskeleton.ListUsersActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The activity_login.xml(Layout file for LoginActivity):

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.sinch.messagingtutorial.app.LoginActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/username"
        android:id="@+id/loginUsernameText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/sinch_purple"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/sinch_purple"
        android:background="@drawable/inputbox"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:id="@+id/loginPasswordText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/sinch_purple"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/sinch_purple"
        android:background="@drawable/inputbox"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_login"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signupButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_signup"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The activity_list_users.xml(UserListActivity layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.sinch.messagingtutorial.app.ListUsersActivity"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/logout"
    android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/sinch_purple" />

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@color/off_white"
    android:id="@+id/usersListView">
 </ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Getting error when putting logcat here, so i uploaded it to pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/nzg2YbfZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the logcat you've posted.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: You must call Parse.initialize(context, oauthKey, oauthSecret) before using the Parse library.
        at com.parse.ParseUser.checkApplicationContext(ParseUser.java:1104)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser(ParseUser.java:904)
        at com.sinch.messagingtutorialskeleton.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:24)
```

if you check the code references this line (LoginActivity:24)...

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

I have not used that library, but is clear you have to invoke

```
Parse.initialize(this, "**parse key**","**parse key**");
```

Before **ParseUser.getCurrentUser();**

** For the second crash in ListUserActivity **

Split the line on two, so you can check if the "getCurrentUser()" method is failing:

```
...
// Line 65
ParseUser mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); // Breakpoint here in Android Studio and go step by step for checking return value
currentUserId = mCurrentUser.getObjectId();
...
```

A suggestion for debugging...

Comment: I did it and the app main activity showed up but in the transition to the second activity it force closes

Comment: Check your logcat again, it will tell you where is the problem force-closing your app

Comment: Check "getCurrentUser()" as it seems to return null, so you are trying to access a non-existent method "getObjectId()" on null (ListsUserActivity:56)

Comment: Im really new into this, could you make this more understable?

Comment: This in what activity login or listuser?

Comment: On ListUser, would be great if you can upvote the answer also ;) @GrStorm

Answer (score 0):

Try moving:

```
setContentView(com.example.messagingtutorialskeleton.R.layout.activity_login);
Parse.initialize(this, "uUv5HM8nqz9gVQBDWaw1bDLxbD3SFQPQtvDESJG1","BHVp4MQbiOODY3yGOrM7pgaZ0xTbCPI1v6dfRU6C");
loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
signUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUsername);
passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
```

up before:

```
if (currentUser != null) {
    //start new activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListUsersActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

after:

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

I'm just guessing that when you start the activity, it just stops there, and doesn't get to the rest of the stuff, **including** Parse.initialize();

**EDIT:**

As Frederic said below, it references to that line, which is, suspiciously, right before it calls the activity, and it says that there should be Parse.initialize() in the place of that line, OR BEFORE YOU START THE NEW ACTIVITY.

Comment: Yes i did, and the problem continues